# .htaccess image redirect (different directory)

Tags: php, wordpress, image, .htaccess

Can somebody help me with an image redirect in .htaccess?
I need to replace
http://www.example.com/wp/folder_changes/6/bg6.png
with
http://www.example.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/folder_changes/bg6.png
The '6' can be any number and any length.

I only have some regular expression experience and came up with this:

```
\/wp\/(.*)\/(.*)\/bg(\d*).png$
```

How do you re-assemble it again?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /wp/(.*)/(.*)/bg(\d*).png$ /wp/wp-content/uploads/???/bg???.png
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want:

```
RewriteRule wp/(.*)/(.*)/bg(\d*).png$ /wp/wp-content/uploads/$1/bg$3.png
```

Comment: @greg-bornonus Thanks. Do I just paste it like this into my .htaccess file with the standard wordpress code? 
`# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wp/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wp/index.php [L]
RewriteRule /home/htmlcolor/public_html/wp/(.*)/(.*)/bg(\d*).png$ /home/htmlcolor/public_html/wp/wp-content/uploads/$1/bg$2.png
</IfModule>
# END WordPress`

Comment: that's not formatted very well, but you add it as a new line after all the other rules, right before </IfModule>\

Comment: Yes, I don't know how to format it better in the comment but each item is on a line.
Question, this would work for an embedded file, correct? I am embedding a file that references http://www.example.com/wp/folder_changes/6/bg6.png

Comment: So http://www.example.com/wp/folder_changes/ would contain an image http://www.example.com/wp/folder_changes/6/bg6.png but I want it to use the source http://www.example.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/folder_changes/bg6.png

Comment: It doesn't need to exist, but it can exist

Comment: I sort of figured it out. I think the reason it doesn't work is that the file doesn't exist. For example http://www.example.com/wp/folder_changes/6/bg6.png doesn't exist yet I still want it to load http://www.example.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/folder_changes/bg6.png

Comment: I just realized that if you add it where I told you too, it won't work. You need to add it right after the engine on statement. And you need to add a conditional so the rest if your site works. I'll update my answer when I get back to the computer

Comment: Yes, I managed to get it to work on another testing website by placing it at the top after rewriteengine on, but the scenario is different. Thanks again for your help. So far I have this: 
`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /(.*)/(.*)/bg(\d*)(\w*).png /wp-content/uploads/$1/bg$2$4.png
RewriteBase /wp/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wp/index.php [L]
</IfModule>`

Comment: No problem Let me know if you need anything else

Comment: Actually can you tell me what conditional I need to add?

Comment: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /bg #make sure the url contains /bg. If you have any other rules that are better, like /folder_changes might be better

Comment: Is this how I should piece it togther? `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /(.*)/(.*)/bg(\d*)(\w*).png /wp-content/uploads/$1/bg$2$4.png
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /bg
RewriteBase /wp/ 
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule . /wp/index.php [L] 
</IfModule>`

Comment: I'm very close to solving it. Do you know why
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)/bg(.*).png$ wp-content/uploads/folder_name/bg$3.png [NC] works fine, but
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)/bg(.*).png$ wp-content/uploads/$1/bg$3.png [NC] doesn't? $1 is the same as folder_name.
It works on http://htaccess.mwl.be/

Comment: In your question, you used http://www.example.com/wp/folder_changes/6/bg6.png as your example. If that is the url, $1 will be /folder_changes. because your regex only matches the end, and it only goes back 4 directories. To include wp, I would use this instead: RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/bg(.*).png$  $1/wp-content/uploads/$2/bg$4.png

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!!